# tickinterval not working high chart for x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/rtmv01gn/5/) to a fiddle where i have tried plot the x axis using datetime and passed on multiple series with data points.
Here i am unable to attain the tick marks for month of December and February

sample x axis

```
    xAxis: {

        type: 'datetime',
        //minTickInterval: 2419200000, //time in milliseconds
        //minRange: 2419200000,


        //showLastLabel: true,
        tickInterval: 2419200000,

    },
```

sample data points in series

```
   {            
        "data": [{

            "x": 1420070400000,
            "y": 2,
        }, {

            "x": 1425168000000,
            "y": 1,                
        }],           
        "name": "Neither Dissatisfied or Satisfied",
        "color": "#5aa5dc",          
    }
```

plz help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) parameter as single month.

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,

    },
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            pointRange:30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rtmv01gn/9/

Comment: Thanks...
 Sebastian Bochan